# Grouped Bar Plot: How do I order according to the change in score?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I've checked many questions similar to this one but I believe my query is a unique one. I have three columns: habits (factor variable: 4 levels), score and time (factor variable: 3 levels).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

habits <- c("Eating", "Drinking", "Walking", "Running",
            "Eating", "Drinking", "Walking", "Running",
            "Eating", "Drinking", "Walking", "Running")
score <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 2), size = 12, replace = TRUE)

time_1 <- c("0", "3", "6")

time <- rep(time_1, 4)

df <- data.frame(habits, score, time)
df %>% arrange(time)

    habits score time
1    Eating     8    0
2   Running     4    0
3   Walking     8    0
4  Drinking     6    0
5  Drinking     6    3
6    Eating     4    3
7   Running     4    3
8   Walking     4    3
9   Walking     6    6
10 Drinking     2    6
11   Eating     4    6
12  Running     0    6

ggplot(df, aes(x = habits, y = score, fill = time)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image: Initial BarPlot]

Basically, I am tracking habits over a period of time. I want to make a grouped-bar plot with the condition that the highest **change in score** should come first. For this, I first calculate change:

```r
df <-  df %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(change = score - lag(score)) %>% 
    arrange(time) %>% mutate(change = replace_na(change, 0)) 
# Replacing NA's because the variables don't show up.
```

From the previous post, I saw that `reorder` function can be used to make the change necessary.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(habits, -change), y = score, fill = time, group = habits)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

I get a stacked bar-plot.

[image: Stacked BarPlot]

Finally, I reordered according to fill and while its closer to what I want.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = habits, y = score, fill = reorder(time, -change), group = change)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image: BarPlot sorted with greatest change?]

I see that the factors have reversed (notice that the blue bar is now in the front). I checked the levels of the `time` and its 0,3,6. So I don't know why its not showing up correctly. **I also don't think the graph is correct because the values of the score have changed.** I simply want to show the graph that should come first.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly, shouldn't you group by "habits" instead of by "time" in the chain where you calculate the lagged difference?

Comment: I don't know. I wanted calculate the change in values on time. For example, what is the difference in drinking at time 0 and time 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that labels the change from time 0 to time 6 and orders by that number. For transparency I'm giving each "habits" category a new name that also includes the change, to clarify that's how it's sorting.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(
  habits = c("Eating", "Drinking", "Walking", "Running",
            "Eating", "Drinking", "Walking", "Running",
            "Eating", "Drinking", "Walking", "Running"),
  score = sample(seq(from = 0, to = 10, by = 2), size = 12, replace = TRUE),
  time = rep(c("0", "3", "6"), 4))

df %>% 
  complete(habits, time) %>%
  group_by(habits) %>%
  mutate(change = score[time == "6"] - score[time == "0"]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(habits = paste(habits, change, sep = "\n") %>%
           fct_reorder(change)) %>% 
  #mutate(habits = fct_reorder(habits, change)) %>% # w/o chg # 
  ggplot(aes(x = habits, y = score, fill = time)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: What I ended up doing ultimately is to reorder factor levels based on the change. Its not perfect but its getting me somewhere. I'm using `fct_reorder(habits, change)` to reorder factors according to maximum change.